# suddenly undefined array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, genetic-algorithm

I am messing with a genetic algorithm for curiosity.

I was doing the generation switch part when I hit a wall. I removed the parents for the next generation from the previous actors array, pushed them in a parents array and was proceding to remove random parent pairs from the parents array and store them in progen1 and progen2 variables, but for some reason the inner array cromossomo of progen1 was undefined, event though I could access its elements when it progen1 whas stored in parents array.

This code:

```
var n1=Math.floor((Math.random(Math.floor(parents.length))));
console.log(parents[n1].cromossomo[0]);
var progen1=parents.splice(n1);
console.log(progen1.cromossomo[0]);
var n2=Math.floor((Math.random(Math.floor(parents.length))));
var progen2=parents.splice(n2);
```

produces:

```
{dx: -4.805923044269889, dy: -2.447397585132567}dx: -4.805923044269889dy: -2.447397585132567__proto__: Object
scripts.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at switchGeneration (scripts.js:94)
at run (scripts.js:140)
```

and I am going crazy not knowing why this is happening!

Comment: what is **parents** here?Show your html also

Comment: is the array where i store the menbers of the previous generation wich had the best fitness

Comment: `splice` returns an _array_. Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). `progen1.cromossomo` won’t exist; you need to get `progen1[0].cromossomo[0]`.

Comment: what do you expect this line to do `var progen1=parents.splice(n1);`?

Comment: I needed to temporary remove the progens from parents due to problems with random numbers generating the exact same number twice

Comment: should i put the entire code here?

Answer (score 1):

`splice()` returns an array of all the elements that were removed from the array. So `progen1` is an array of all the elements of `parents` starting from `n1`, not a single object. The array doesn't have a `cromossomo` property, so `progen1.cromossomo[0]` tries to get the `0` index of `undefined`.

If your intent is to just remove 1 element from `parents`, you need to specify number of elements to remove when you call `splice()`. Then you can index the value to get that element.

```
progen1 = parents.splice(n1, 1)[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message reads: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Looking at your snippet, I find `cromossomo[0]`.

If `cromossomo` is not present in either `parents[n1]` or `progen1`, it is `undefined`, which leads to the error.

So maybe you have a look at these first and verify each of them has a `cromosso`.